# Why Does "re.match" Behavior Change when Under Test?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, pytest

I've run into a bizarre situation where I wrote a test to check for a "re.match" that would definitely fail, but passes when tested in py.test. The code fails as expected when ran outside a test environment.

- OS: Ubuntu 16.04
- Python: 2.7.12
- pytest: 3.5.0

**regex_code.py**

```
import re
import sys


def main():
    regex = re.compile(r'tests\.(test_\w+)\.?(Test\w+)?$')

    input_text = 'test.tests.test_default'

    if regex.match(input_text):
        print('Pass')
        return 0
    else:
        print('Fail')
        return 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

**test_regex_code.py**

```
import pytest
from regex_code import main


def test_main():
    assert 1 == main()
```

When I run **regex_code.py** from the command-line I get following output:

```
$ python regex_code.py

Fail

Process finished with exit code 1
```

When I run **test_regex_code.py** test suite I get the following output:

```
$ pytest test_regex_code.py

============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.12, pytest-3.5.0, py-1.5.3, pluggy-0.6.0
rootdir: /mnt/c/Users/rackspace/code/dummy, inifile:
plugins: helpers-namespace-2017.11.11, flake8dir-1.2.0
collected 1 item                                                               

test_regex_code.py .Fail
                                                     [100%]

=========================== 1 passed in 0.03 seconds ===========================
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Any thoughts on what the root cause is for this difference in behavior?

Comment: You do realize, that you need to `assert main() == 0` because 0 means success, right?

Comment: @swenzel - but the regex fails...

Comment: Yeah, it fails in both cases. Already on the first word, since `'test' != 'tests'`.

Comment: But it passes in pytest because you assert that it fails

Comment: In `test_regex_code.py .Fail` the dot means it ran a test and the Fail just happens to be what the script prints. You test for 1 meaning you want the fail to happen, so the unit test passes. Its a positive test for failure.

Comment: @swenzel I was a bit terse there! Tests for failure are normal. You want the test to pass on the known fail. Had he tested for 0, the unit test would fail and a bug would need to be fixed.

Comment: Uhhh, sorry the code is working as expected. My brain is not. ::bagofshame::

Comment: Yeah, sorry for that... was hoping my first comment would already make you realize what is happening. :D